# have/has + been + 3rd verb form

Tags: passive-voice, subjects

I know this sentence:

> your message has been sent

the subject is no known.

I know this sentence:

> you have been registered.

the subject is no known.

but what is this:

> I have been really worried these past few days ?

here the subject is known , how this is good grammer? why the author not say : "I was worried" ?
sorry my english is bad

Comment: worried is a verb , right?

Comment: "worried" in your example is an adjective, "to be" is the verb

Comment: @fluffy this is the whole sentnce, so it doesn't have a verb ???

Comment: @JoeDimaggio but I know that after Have been , i have to put verb +ing If there is a subject, right?

Comment: Smolina, "to be" is the verb, it is in Present Perfect, "have been". Compare: *I have been really tired/bored/thirsty/frustrated*, etc.

Comment: @fluffy is this correct ? I have been worring about my exam for the last week

Comment: It is correct. In this case it is a different tense from before. Notice that all my examples can not be transformed in this way, all of the following are wrong: *I have been tiring/boring/thirstying/frustrating for three days*. This should show you that the two things are different. It simply works with "worry" both times, this is a coincidence.

Comment: @fluffy so what is the verb (or nouns i don't know) which can be with ing and which is no can ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. And it seems to be different from the one you asked in the first place.

Comment: Smolina, problem is that some verbs are not often used in progressive form and among them there are verbs describing mental and emotional states, like those fluffy wrote.

Comment: @Carlo_R. do you has the all list for that verbs?

Comment: Smolina, there are a lot, however the following list consents you to start: believe, doubt, feel, hate, imagine, know, like, love, prefer, realize, recognise, remember, see, suppose, think, understand, want, wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two are examples of present perfect passive. The verbs are respectively "has been sent" and "have been registered". We do not know who did it, that is why we use the passive. *Sent* and *registered* are the past participles of the verbs *send* and *register*.

The third sentence is an example of present perfect active, where the verb is "have been" (*worried* is an adjective). You can put it in any tense you want, depending on the context, for example "I was worried about you but now I am fine." or "I have never been more worried in my life."

If you expand the second example further, you will see that *worried* can not be the verb in this sentence: "I have never been (quite) as worried about you as in these past few hours."

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem over terminology here. Since ELL is about learning *language*, we should probably stick to the standard meaning of the word "subject" in matters of grammar. Highlighted subjects are...

> ***Your message*** has been sent.
>    ***You*** have been registered.

The undefined but implicit referent is the [agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_%28grammar%29) (who/whatever *sent* the message, or *registered* you).

We assume there must be such an entity in those examples, because the meanings of the verbs involved require that there's an *agent* acting upon an [object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29) (technically speaking, acting on a [patient](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/101313/2637)).

If the agent is explicitly specified, it may well also be the grammatical "subject"...

> ***John*** has sent your message.
>    ***John*** has registered you.

...but the agent might not be the subject even when present...

> ***Your message*** has been sent by John.
>    ***You*** have been registered by John.

---

Turning to...

> ***I*** have been really worried these past few days. (again, with the "grammatical subject" highlighted)

...the verb *to worry* doesn't normally imply an *agent* acting on an *object/patient* (there's only really you involved if you say [I worry when I go to bed at night](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20worry%20when%20I%20go%20to%20bed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)).

Semantically, there's not much to differentiate Present Tense *I worry* from the [passive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/081021/) version *I am worried*. Essentially, the verb *to worry* is simply being used to create an "adjectival" *worried* from the past tense, but follow that link if you want the BBC's fine distinction (which I wouldn't bother too much about).

The "headline" difference between Present Perfect **passive** (not *active*, I don't think)...

> *1: **I** have been really worried these past few days.*

...and Simple Past passive...

> *2: **I** was worried.*

...arises from the fact that Present Perfect (as per the name) implies a stronger connection/continuity *from the past to the present time* (which may by extension emphasise the *duration* more). But this is also a "fine distinction". In practice, OP's #1 and #2 are mainly just stylistic choices.

---

(I can't resist putting this section in, but note that it's not relevant to all learners... :)

The verb *to worry* can have an *agent* and a *patient*, particularly when it has OED's sense 3a...

> trans. *To seize by the throat with the teeth and tear or lacerate; to kill or injure by biting and shaking.* Said e.g. of **dogs** or wolves **attacking sheep**, or of hounds when they seize their quarry.

So if we can postulate a sheep who speaks English, she might say...

> I was worried yesterday.

...then grammatically, she might mean either of...

> ***That new untrained sheepdog*** worried me (it attacked me).
>    ***I*** was worried (e.g. - that the new dog might not be able to herd us back into the pen in time for tea).